# Show/hide callback with jQuery Masonry?

Tags: jquery, callback, load, jquery-masonry

I want to hide my content until Masonry has had a chance to style it (to prevent the dreaded flash of unstyled content), and then hide the loader gif . Here is a code snippet:

```
var $container = $('#deals');

$(window).load(function(){    
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.deals-wrapper',
        columnWidth : 0,
        isFitWidth: true
    });
},
function() {
    $container.show();
    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

However, I notice that when .show() is called, Masonry hasn't been applied to the content. I know in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251681/jquery-masonry-callback-not-working), the creator of Masonry suggested that there isn't good support for Masonry callbacks right now. Has anyone come up with a decent workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use css to hide the element as long as its loading.
Also there is the `.imagesLoaded()` function. You can see an example in my [recent Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227811/drupal-attachbehaviours-with-jquery-infinitescroll-and-jquery-masonry).