# Drupal.attachBehaviours with jQuery infinitescroll and jQuery masonry

Tags: drupal-7, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am a little desperate here. I have been reading everything I was able to find on Drupal.behaviours but obviously its still not enough. I try running a masonry grid with the infinitescroll plugin to attach the new images to the masonry. This works fine so far. The next thing I wanted to implement to my website is a hover effect (which shows information on the images) and later fancybox to show the images in a huger size.

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.views_fluidgrid = {
        attach: function (context) {
            $('.views-fluidgrid-wrapper:not(.views-fluidgrid-processed)', context).addClass('views-fluidgrid-processed').each(function () {
                // hide items while loading
                var $this = $(this).css({opacity: 0}),      
                id = $(this).attr('id'),
                settings = Drupal.settings.viewsFluidGrid[id];

                $this.imagesLoaded(function() {
                    // show items after .imagesLoaded()
                    $this.animate({opacity: 1});
                    $this.masonry({
                        //the masonry settings
                    });
                });

                //implement the function of jquery.infinitescroll.min.js
                $this.infinitescroll({
                    //the infinitescroll settings
                },

                //show new items and attach behaviours in callback
                function(newElems) {
                    var newItems = $(newElems).css({opacity: 0});
                    $(newItems).imagesLoaded(function() {
                        $(newItems).animate({opacity: 1});
                        $this.masonry('appended', newItems);
                        Drupal.attachBehaviours(newItems);
                    });
                });

            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now I read that I need to Reattach the Drupal.behaviours if I want the hover event to also take place on the newly added content.

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.imgOverlay = {
        attach: function (context) {
            var timeout;
            $('.img_gallery').hover(function() {
                $this = $(this);
                timeout = setTimeout(change_opacity, 500);
                }, reset_opacity);

            function change_opacity() {
                //set opacity to show the desired elements
            }

            function reset_opacity() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                //reset opacity to 0 on desired elements
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery)
```

Where do I now write the Drupal.attachBehaviours() to make it work actually? Or is there some other error I just dont see atm? I hope I wrote the question so that its understandable and maybe it also helps somebody else, since I experienced that there is no real "official" running Version of this combination in drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution is actually pretty simple. When writing it correctly than it also runs. its of course not `Drupal.attachBehaviours()` but `Drupal.attachBehaviors()` . So this combination now works and I am finally relieved :).